# How can I insert data into Access database fields?

Tags: sql, forms, insert, ms-access-2007, edit

I have created multiple forms and each contains multiple buttons. The end-user will go through the forms sequentially where he selects one button and goes to the next form and so on.

I also created a table that stores the entered data. For example; if the user clicks Button A, the designated field will have value of "A" and so on. In other words, each button will enter a certain data into a specific field.

What I wanted eventually is to have a complete record set (row) after the set of forms finishes.

I used the following code inside the very first button in the first form

```
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Data", dbOpenDynaset)
RS.AddNew
RS("WLAN") = "ARUBA"
RS.Update
Set RS = Nothing
```

In the later forms (buttons), I used the following code

```
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Data", dbOpenDynaset)
RS.Edit
RS("Security") = "WPA2-PSK"
RS.Update
Set RS = Nothing
```

Now what happens is that the first sequence of forms (buttons) successfully enter data into the first row in my table [Data] but when I start over and select other buttons, the existing row get edited with the new selections.

What I want is to add a new record and insert data into it and not to edit the previous one.

I will highly appreciate your kind help and i'm sorry for the long post.

Thank you,
Nasser

Comment: Before you edit you will need to locate the record you want to update. However you are better of collecting all the data and adding it at the same time rather than add, update, update, update......

Comment: This might help  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243797(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Thanks Fred but can you please show me how to do both options. I prefer the first option because it would be difficult for me to collect all the data since I have many forms. Or is there any other way?

Comment: One more thing to explain, I want to insert multiple records but after the first loop it keeps going back to the previous one and edits all the existing data.

Comment: That link I posted shows you how to locate a record for updating. Im guessing you have some field that is a unique identifier? IE. An auto incremented field? Some value in a field that only that record has.

Comment: Exactly. I have an automatic-generated ID field but I don't want to edit or update the records. I want to insert more ones without going back and edit the first or the existing one.

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to hold the id of the record you are working on. I will call it `RecId` for this example.

To add a record

```
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Data", dbOpenDynaset)
RS.AddNew
RS("WLAN") = "ARUBA"
RecId = RS("ID")
RS.Update
Set RS = Nothing
```

Then to Update the same record

```
Dim RS As DAO.Recordset
Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Data", dbOpenDynaset)
RS.MoveFirst
Do Until RS.EOF
    If RD!ID= RecId Then
        RS.Edit
        RS("Security") = "WPA2-PSK"
        RS.Update
    End If
    RS.MoveNext
Loop
Set RS = Nothing
```

If you never want to update any records and only ever want to add new then only use the add code.  You will need to put a few check in but this should give you the basis of what you need.

Comment: Sorry for being late. I really appreciate it Fred. I will try your suggestion and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: I tried the Update code but it didn't work. It didn't add anything to the table. At first I created an integer called RecId and then I changed RD to RS in this line

    If RD!ID= RecId Then

but that didn't help either. Thanks

Comment: It worked! I used the following code:
    Dim RS As dao.Recordset
    Dim RecID As Integer
    Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Data", dbOpenDynaset)
    RecID = DLast("[ID]", "Data")
    RS.MoveFirst
    Do Until RS.EOF
    If RS("ID") = RecID Then
            RS.Edit
            RS("ControllerVersion") = "5.x"
            RS.Update
        
            End If
            RS.MoveNext
    Loop
    Set RS = Nothing

Thanks Fred. I really appreciate it.